# Is there a command line tool to use SQS on an AWS ec2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How do I interact with SQS on ec2 via the command line? I cannot find an SQS tool in AWS developer tools.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command line tool for dealing with [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/code/developertools/739). However I have found that the best way to interact is with an SDK. The [Ruby sdk](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html) allows you to work with almost all of the AWS toolset. You simple just write a one-off ruby script to do whatever you need with the AWS Service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python, [boto](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/sqs_tut.html) is a great utility for working with AWS services.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli supports SQS. From `aws sqs help`:

```
AVAILABLE COMMANDS
   o add-permission

   o change-message-visibility

   o change-message-visibility-batch

   o create-queue

   o delete-message

   o delete-message-batch

   o delete-queue

   o get-queue-attributes

   o get-queue-url

   o list-queues

   o receive-message

   o remove-permission

   o send-message

   o send-message-batch

   o set-queue-attributes

   o help
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this script I made. It allows only the essential interactions with Amazon SQS (receiving, sending and deleting messages). You will need to build it using Go on the environment you are running (which is pretty simple to do. Just run go build). Let me know if you have questions (on the github issues page) or having trouble installing the script on your server/dev machine! I use this script extensively on Heroku.

https://github.com/lancecarlson/sqslite

Sending a message:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=whatever
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=whatever
echo "message" | sqslite -q queue-name -c s
```

Receiving a message:

```
sqslite -q queue-name
```

Deleting a message:

```
echo "ReceiptHandlerId" | sqslite -q queue-name -c d
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Are my amendments sufficient? You could go the other way and say that if I include usage/documentation of the script here that this could get outdated. I do see your point though.

Comment: @LucasZamboulis Do you mind not down voting this if the answer is sufficient ?

Comment: Do you mind not assuming that I was the one that downvoted you?